# CLion not using the correct compiler?

Tags: clion

I get this output when I run cmake in the CLion environment. When I run outside of CLion I get no warnings and everything works fine.

The really strange part about this is I specify clang and clang++ for the compiler, I do this in the CC and CXX environment variables as well as in the toolchain settings in CLion, but it is saying the g++ and gcc are having errors. However, no where in any of my config for CLion have I mentioned gcc or g++.

Where are these coming from and how can I fix it? It would be really nice to actually build this project from my IDE.

These issues started after the CLion 2017.3 update.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/make -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /home/rkratt/src
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.9.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.9.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Building src in Debug mode.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/rkratt/src/cmake-build-debug

Problems were encountered while collecting compiler information:
    g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-fopenmp=libomp'
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fopenmp=libomp'

[Finished]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ryan, it seems that CMake associated g++/gcc with specific targets in you project. I suspect that building will also fail. Could you check that?

If you are not able to resolve the problem, please file [a ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP) and we'll try to help.

Comment: Yes, building also fails.